# SP flash tool not starting

Tags: rom-flashing, rom, flashtool

I'm trying to flash my Micromax Canvas A1 (AQ4501). I'm following [this guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/canvas-a1/development/official-stock-rom-canvas-a1-t2887150). As per the instruction, when I click on download I should connect my phone. Now, my device gets detected by Windows (see the image below).

[image: Device gets connected]

But the download is not starting. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging up I found out that I had not unlocked the OEM.

1. Pressed and hold Power + Volume Up
2. Choosen Fastboot on the menu
3. On fastboot command line ran 
    `unlock.bat`
   and then `fastboot oem unlock`
4. Selected yes on the device
5. Disconnected the device.
6. Started SP tool
7. Connected the device, flashing starts and completes.